# json table group by

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i want to query my data in my database (i'm use mariadb version 10.6)
this is my data

```
[{"STAFF_ID": 287, "DATE": "2022-03-30 14:54:37", "ACTION": "UPDATE", "TABLE": "m_course", "COLUMN": ["ID", "COURSE"] ,"OLD": [287, "Physics"], "NEW": [396,"Chemistry"]}]
```

and this is my query

```
    SELECT
    lg.ID,
    lg.MONTH_YEAR,
    P.NAMA,
    d.* 
   FROM
    log_akses_pegawai_json lg,
    json_table (
        lg.ACADEMIC,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            id VARCHAR ( 10 ) path '$.STAFF_ID',
            date VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.DATE',
            action VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.ACTION',
            mytable VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.TABLE',
            nested path '$.COLUMN[*]' COLUMNS ( mycolumn VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ),
            nested path '$.OLD[*]' COLUMNS ( old VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ),
            nested path '$.NEW[*]' COLUMNS ( new VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ) 
        )) AS d
    LEFT JOIN m_pegawai P ON P.ID_PEGAWAI = d.id;
```

and the result is
[image: and the result is]

but i want to merge the record (merge the null value), because is must be just 2 record

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nested path, json explodes producing multiple rows.
you will have to do a max value to dedup and eliminate nulls.

```
select ID, MONTH_YEAR, NAMA, max(id1), max(date), max(action), max(mytable), max(mycolumn), max(old), max(new)
from (
SELECT
    lg.ID,
    lg.MONTH_YEAR,
    P.NAMA,
    d.* 
   FROM
    log_akses_pegawai_json lg,
    json_table (
        lg.ACADEMIC,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            id VARCHAR ( 10 ) path '$.STAFF_ID',
            date VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.DATE',
            action VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.ACTION',
            mytable VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.TABLE',
            nested path '$.COLUMN[*]' COLUMNS ( mycolumn VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ),
            nested path '$.OLD[*]' COLUMNS ( old VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ),
            nested path '$.NEW[*]' COLUMNS ( new VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ) 
        )) AS d
    LEFT JOIN m_pegawai P ON P.ID_PEGAWAI = d.id)
group by ID, MONTH_YEAR, NAMA;
```

Answer (score 0):

- It's not smart to use `*` in such queries. Now you have two field that are named `id`. (that's why I added an alias for the first one to `ID2`)
- I also added `rwc`,`rwo` and `rwn` for ordinality. They produce the rownumber for the detail (see: [ordinality columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/#ordinality-columns)
- The old-style join between `lg.ACADEMIC` and the JSON_TABLE is corrected  (see: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins))

This produces:

| ID22 | MONTH_YEAR | NAMA | id | date | action | mytable | rwc | mycolumn | rwo | old | rwn | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course | 1 | ID |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course | 2 | COURSE |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course |  |  | 1 | 287 |  |  |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course |  |  | 2 | Physics |  |  |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course |  |  |  |  | 1 | 396 |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course |  |  |  |  | 2 | Chemistry |

Which can be queries using some INNER JOINs:

```
WITH result as(
 SELECT
    lg.ID as ID22,
    lg.MONTH_YEAR,
    P.NAMA,
    d.* 
   FROM
    log_akses_pegawai_json lg
    CROSS JOIN json_table(
        lg.ACADEMIC,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            id VARCHAR ( 10 ) path '$.STAFF_ID',
            date VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.DATE',
            action VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.ACTION',
            mytable VARCHAR ( 20 ) path '$.TABLE',
            nested path '$.COLUMN[*]' COLUMNS ( rwc for ordinality, mycolumn VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ),
            nested path '$.OLD[*]' COLUMNS ( rwo for ordinality, old VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ),
            nested path '$.NEW[*]' COLUMNS ( rwn for ordinality, new VARCHAR ( 32 ) path '$' ) 
        )) AS d
    LEFT JOIN m_pegawai P ON P.ID_PEGAWAI = lg.ID
) 
select 
   rc.ID22 as ID,
   rc.MONTH_YEAR,
   rc.NAMA,
   rc.id,
   rc.`date`,
   rc.action,
   rc.mytable,
   rc.mycolumn,
   ro.old,
   rn.new
from result rc
inner join result ro on rc.rwc=ro.rwo
inner join result rn on rc.rwc=rn.rwn
where rc.rwc is not null
;
```

output:

| ID | MONTH_YEAR | NAMA | id | date | action | mytable | mycolumn | old | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course | COURSE | Physics | Chemistry |
| 16 | 202204 |  | 287 | 2022-03-30 14:54:37 | UPDATE | m_course | ID | 287 | 396 |

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6cd1a3dba7fcfb6ea6122343a6d843e1)

EDIT: The column `NAMA` is empty, this is due to incorrect data on my site. In the DBFIDDLE the column has data.

Comment: thanks bro this way is working
but there is bug if we have data more than 1 record
the data is duplicate